# How to validate phone field?

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

How can I validate phone field for below format:

```
(999) 999-9999
```

I have tried with below, but not working.

```
if(array_key_exists('phone', $values) && $values['phone'] != '')
{
  if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/', $values['phone']))
  {
    $form_state->setErrorByName('phone', t('Please enter a valid phone number.'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost did it: the `{3}` should quantify the `[0-9]` and the literal parentheses should be added escaped with a backslash:

```
if(array_key_exists('phone', $values) && !empty($values['phone']))
  {
    if(!preg_match('/\A\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}\z/', $values['phone']))
    {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('phone', t('Please enter a valid phone number.'));
    }
  }
```

I also suggest using `!empty($values['phone'])` and `\A` / `\z` anchors that always match the start / the very end of the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bVU4AV/1):

- `\A` - unambiguous start of the string anchor
- `\(` - an open parenthesis
- `[0-9]{3}` - 3 digits
- `\)` - a closing parenthesis
- - a space
- `[0-9]{3}`  - 3 digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]{4}` - 4 digits
- `\z` - the very end of the string.